# Get nearest store location for all users

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables, one for store with zipcode, longitude and latitude.
Another for users with same data i.e zipcode, longitude and latitude.

I need to find out nearest store for all users, and their distance.

```
SELECT 
user.zipcode, 
(
   3959 *
   acos(cos(radians(37.423021)) * 
   cos(radians(store_lat)) * 
   cos(radians(store_lng) - 
   radians(user_long)) + 
   sin(radians(user_lat)) * 
   sin(radians(lat )))
) AS distance 
FROM locations
ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Spatial functions** provided with Amazon Redshift.

From [ST_DistanceSphere - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/ST_DistanceSphere-function.html):

> `ST_DistanceSphere` returns the distance between two point geometries lying on a sphere.
> ...
> The following example SQL computes the distances in kilometers between three airport locations in Germany: Berlin Tegel (TXL), Munich International (MUC), and Frankfurt International (FRA).

```sql
WITH airports_raw(code,lon,lat) AS (
(SELECT 'MUC', 11.786111, 48.353889) UNION
(SELECT 'FRA', 8.570556, 50.033333) UNION
(SELECT 'TXL', 13.287778, 52.559722)),

airports1(code,location) AS (SELECT code, ST_Point(lon, lat) FROM airports_raw),

airports2(code,location) AS (SELECT * from airports1)

SELECT
  (airports1.code || ' <-> ' || airports2.code) AS airports,
  round(ST_DistanceSphere(airports1.location, airports2.location) / 1000, 0) AS distance_in_km
FROM airports1, airports2
WHERE airports1.code < airports2.code ORDER BY 1;
```

Result:

```
  airports   | distance_in_km 
-------------+----------------
 FRA <-> MUC |            299
 FRA <-> TXL |            432
 MUC <-> TXL |            480
```